# What is happening in this C code when return is called?

Tags: c, return

This may seem a crass question but it is important. Can anyone tell me what is happening in this C code and what is the value of n when it returns?

MAX_BUFFER is set to 256. I am especially interested in variable n when it is returned.

```
int getinteger(void) {
    char buff[MAX_BUFFER];
    int i;
    int n;
    /* Strip leading comments and blank lines */
    do {
        fgets(buff, sizeof (buff), stdin);
        i = strspn(buff, " ");
    } while (buff[i] == '#' || buff[i] == '\n');
    if (sscanf(buff + i, "%d", &n) != 1) {
        fatal("Getinteger error (%s)", buff);
    }
    return n;
}
```

When called a value of -2 is returned. I do not understand why.

Comment: Nothing useful is happening. Having a non-empty return statement in a void function is a setup for undefined behavior due to a constraint violation.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I can't. Since you edited your answer to fix that nonsense

Comment: @StoryTeller that is not in the edit history.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Grace period. There was a void there

Comment: As is variable n.

Comment: First problem counting in while is not limited add && i<254. n is not initalized. buff + i can be a random adress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `n` will depend on the input.

It basically reads lines, until it finds one that doesn't start with `#` or is blank. Leading spaces are ignored, that's what the call to `strspn()` does.

Once such a non-empty line is found, it is expected to contain a decimal integer, which is converted (using `sscanf()` and stored in the local variable `n`) and returned. If the conversion fails, an error is printed.

Comment: But how is n populated? I can see nothing that explicitly sets it.

Comment: @MrMorgan If you don't find any lines that could be scanned, the value in the address of n is garbage. It just so happened to be -2. Your code is in high risk for undefined behavior since you don't ever explicitly initialize n. If you don't find a blank line then access n, you get undefined behavior - such as when you get -2.. (I think..). To avoid this, always initialize you variables: int i = 0;

Comment: @MrMorgan Then you need to look harder, especially at that `sscanf()` call. :)